# checkbox always passing false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have this form in a view

```
div
  = label_tag "choice[has_pictures]", "Choice can have pictures?"
  = check_box_tag "choice[has_pictures]", choice.has_pictures, choice.has_pictures
```

but, everytime I submit it, I always get the parameter `has_pictures` as false. I don't know what I'm missing, if it's something with slim or not

I'm using Rails 4.0.11

Comment: may be use explicit conversion: `check_box_tag "choice[has_pictures]", choice.has_pictures && 1 || 0, choice.has_pictures` for value?

Comment: it is now passing always 0, as seen ` "choice"=>{"title"=>"Title", "has_pictures"=>"0"},` even with checkbox selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you could put a breakpoint (even within a view!) and check what is the value of that `choice.has_pictures`.

Probably, it is `nil` or there may be an error with your method name, as most of them are called in a way when boolean-returning method' name ends with a question mark: `choice.has_pictures?` (and that is the good practice to have such a wrapping method for a model' boolean field).

There's nothing wrong with Slim - it just puts to the output the result of the Rails' helper method `check_box_tag` call.

Yet, there's one more hint from [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag): you're using the wrong `value` attribute for the `check_box_tag` method:

`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`

If your model has no pictures (`has_pictures == false`), the corresponding param will be returning `false` when the checkbox is checked and `nil` when it's not.

Check this out:

```
<input value="false" name="option_name" />
```

If it is checked, then `params["option_name"] == false`. If it is not, `params["option_name"] == nil`.

So, I'd suggest you to use this in a more convenient way:

```
= check_box_tag "choice[has_pictures]", true, choice.has_pictures
```

Comment: Actually, has_pictures is a boolean field on my class `Choice`, so, I cannot call `has_pictures?` I put a breakpoint on controller, right before the first line, and I always get `false`

Comment: @LuizE. sure, added some more info and now finishing up the answer.

Comment: I did this, and somehow, worked: `check_box_tag "choice[has_pictures]", choice.has_pictures.nil? ? 0 : 1, choice.has_pictures`

Comment: @LuizE. as I mentioned in my answer, it's better to use it this way: `= check_box_tag "choice[has_pictures]", true, choice.has_pictures`

Comment: @LuizE. in your case, `has_pictures.nil? ? 0 : 1` will set `has_pictures` to `false` the first time user saves it and only then it will start working well.

Comment: @LuizE. just take care of what you pass to the methods - Ruby is weakly typed language and does not always checks what you pass ;)